# How to fix an iterator missing error in a typescript without adding an iterator - angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iterator, iteration

My component has a variable

```
songs: Array<any>;
```

in `ngOnInit` i do the following

```
this.songs = new Array();
this.musicService.get()
  .subscribe(r => {
    for(let song of r.body) { // get a list of songs
      let s = song.split('-', 2);
      this.songs.push({ // i just want to put an object
        'artist': s[0],
        'title': s[1]
      ]);
    }
  });
```

This gives an error to the console:

> ERROR in src/app/music/music.component.ts(24,31): error TS2488: Type 'Object' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

I want to use an `object` inside an `array`, I don't need an iterator in this case. How to remove this annoying error without clogging the code with unnecessary iterators?

Comment: ]); should be  }); at the end of the push. Typo?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

typescript type Array have not [Symbol.iterator] ... :( 
But you can use 'forEach'.

[image]

Comment: What for? The error does not disappear if I use your code